# Neo4j - Build Prioritization Rule

Tags: neo4j

We are trying to build a recommendation engine for knowledge management system (KMS) using Neo4j. The idea is to get the published articles that are relevant to a user based on certain criteria and then prioritize the articles to decide the sequence of articles.
For Example - There are a total of 100 articles published in my KMS, out of those 50 are relevant to me based on the metadata properties attached to every article (I have queries that can get me this information), but, I only have a placeholder to show 10 articles.
For this, I have a prioritization matrix that decides the priority of all the 50 articles relevant to me and get the 10 (highly prioritized) that I want to show to the user.
Prioritization matrix is as follows -

Background - Every article will have certain actions - comment, share, like and download. And every colleague will have its own organizational hierarchy like manager, peers, manager of manager etc.

What is required - Every time an action is performed on the article, a score is attached to it. If the action is performed by my manager, it will have a higher score as compared to the action performed by my peer.

Here is the score list:
Actions (Score)-
like (1),
comment (2),
share (5),
download (3)

Association (Multiplication factor) -
Peer (2),
Manager (3),
MOM (3)

Article score formula - ActionScore * AssociationFactor

Scenario -

Article 1 (Liked by my manager and commented by 3 peers) - Score is 1*3 + 3(2*2) = 15
Article 2 (3 Comments added by MOM, liked by 5 peers) - Score is 3(2*3) + 5(1*2) = 28
Article 3 (Commented by 4 peers, liked by MOM and liked by 2 peers) - Score is 4(2*2) + 1*3 + 2(1*2) = 23

According to the score chart, the sequence of my articles should be -
Article 2
Article 3
Article 1

I need to calculate these scores on the fly against all the articles relevant to a colleague and then, return them according to the score attached. How can this be done in Neo4j?

Editted -

Here is the sample code to create two articles, similarly we can create more articles with the desired metadata -

```
CREATE (knowledge:Article { name: 'Article1' }),(bu:BU { name: 'ARS' }),(date:Date { name: 'Date' }),(practice:Practice { name: 'Practice' }),(category:Category { name: 'Category' }),(place:Place { name: 'Place' }),(subcat:Subcategory { name: 'Subacategory' }),(geo:Geography { name: 'US' }),(lang:Language { name: 'Language' }),(trans:Translation { name: 'Translation' }),(keyword:Keyword { name: 'Keyword' }),(colleague1:Colleague { name: 'GS',collid:'567890',BU:'ASC',Country:'India' }),(colleague2:Colleague { name: 'DN',collid:'765432',BU:'ASC',Country:'India' }),(colleague3:Colleague { name: 'PK',collid:'324567',BU:'ASC',Country:'India' }),(colleague4:Colleague { name: 'PMM',collid:'717865',BU:'ARS',Country:'US' }),(knowledge)-[:ASSOCIATED_TO]->(bu),(knowledge)-[:PUBLISHED_ON]->(date),(knowledge)-[:UPDATED_ON]->(date),(knowledge)-[:LIKED_ON]->(date),(knowledge)-[:COMMENTED_ON]->(date),(knowledge)-[:PUBLISHED_IN]->(place),(knowledge)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(geo),(knowledge)-[:IS_OF_SUBTYPE]->(subcat),(knowledge)-[:HAS_ORIGINAL_LANG]->(lang),(knowledge)-[:TRANSLATED_TO]->(trans),(trans)-[:IN_LANGUAGE]->(lang),(knowledge)-[:IS_SUBASSOCIATED_TO]->(practice),(knowledge)-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->(category),(subcat)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(category),(knowledge)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(colleague1),(knowledge)-[:CONTACT_TO]->(colleague1),(knowledge)-[:UPDATED_BY]->(colleague3),(knowledge)-[:LIKED_BY]->(colleague1),(knowledge)-[:COMMENTED_BY]->(colleague1),(colleague1)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]->(colleague2),(colleague1)-[:FOLLOWS]->(colleague2),(colleague1)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]->(colleague4),(colleague1)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]->(colleague3)

MERGE (col1:Colleague { name: 'MK', collid:'98762',BU:'ASC',Country:'US'})
MERGE (col2:Colleague { name: 'AA', collid:'01234567',BU:'ASC',Country:'US'})
MERGE (col3:Colleague { name: 'PM', collid:'45722',BU:'ASC',Country:'US'})

MATCH (col2:Colleague {name:'AA'}),(col1:Colleague { name: 'PM'})
CREATE (col2)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]->(col1)

MATCH (col2:Colleague {name:'PM'}),(col1:Colleague { name: 'MK'})
CREATE (col2)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]->(col1)

MATCH (col2:Colleague {name:'PM'}),(col1:Colleague { name: 'GS'})
CREATE (col2)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]->(col1)

MATCH (colleague:Colleague { name: 'DN' })
MATCH (coll:Colleague { name: 'PK' })
MERGE (knowledge:Article { name: 'Article2' })
MERGE (bu:BU { name: 'ASC' })
MERGE (date:Date { name: 'Date' })
MERGE (practice:Practice { name: 'Practice' })
MERGE (category:Category { name: 'Category' })
MERGE (place:Place { name: 'Place' })
MERGE (subcat:Subcategory { name: 'Subacategory' })
MERGE (geo:Geography { name: 'India' })
MERGE (lang:Language { name: 'English' })
MERGE (trans:Translation { name: 'Translation' })
MERGE (keyword:Keyword { name: 'Keyword' })
MERGE (knowledge)-[:ASSOCIATED_TO]->(bu)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:PUBLISHED_ON]->(date)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:UPDATED_ON]->(date)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:LIKED_ON]->(date)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:COMMENTED_ON]->(date)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:PUBLISHED_IN]->(place)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(geo)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:IS_OF_SUBTYPE]->(subcat)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:HAS_ORIGINAL_LANG]->(lang)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:TRANSLATED_TO]->(trans)
MERGE (trans)-[:IN_LANGUAGE]->(lang)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:IS_SUBASSOCIATED_TO]->(practice)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->(category)
MERGE (subcat)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(category)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(colleague)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:CONTACT_TO]->(colleague)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:UPDATED_BY]->(colleague)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:HAVING]->(keyword)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:LIKED_BY]->(coll)
MERGE (knowledge)-[:COMMENTED_BY]->(coll)

Query to get the org chart of the user -

MATCH (me:Colleague)
WHERE me.collid = '567890'
Return me.name as ColleagueName,me.collid as ColleagueID,0 as Level,true as MyData
Union
MATCH (s:Colleague)<-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]-(me)
WHERE me.collid = '567890'
Return s.name as ColleagueName,s.collid as ColleagueID,-1 as Level,false as MyData
Union
Match (peers:Colleague)<-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]-(mang:Colleague)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]->(me:Colleague)
Where me.collid = '567890'
Return peers.name as ColleagueName,peers.collid as ColleagueID,0 as Level,false as MyData
Union
MATCH path = (m:Colleague)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF*]->(me)
WHERE me.collid = '567890'
Return m.name as ColleagueName,m.collid as ColleagueID,length(path) as Level,false as MyData

Below is the criteria to retrieve articles.

Criteria is to get all articles written by my manager and peers-

Match (n:Article)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(mang:Colleague)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]->(me:Colleague)
Where me.collid='717865'
Return n.name as ArticleName,mang.name as Author,me.name as DataForColleague
Union
Match (n:Article)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(peers:Colleague)<-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]-(mang:Colleague)-[:IS_A_MANAGER_OF]->(me:Colleague)
Where me.collid='717865'
Return n.name as ArticleName,me.name as DataForColleague,peers.name as Author
```

Here, say as an example, if we had a total of 1000 articles (instead of 2 in this example) and the above query would return 50 articles, then, I would need a prioritization logic as explained above to prioritize the articles and get the top 10 articles on the basis of scores calculated.

Comment: It will be better if you show a minimal example of the data, the desired result, and how far you have progressed in the solution. // https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added the sample code in the initial question.